# Переадресация определенного IP на http вместо https

Tags: https, redirect, apache2, mod-rewrite, apache2.4

Есть сайт на хостинге, который настроен и работает по https и http запросы так же переадресовываются через https. Но возникла задача, чтобы конкретный IP мог заходить через обычный http.
В .htaccess сделал правило, поставил первым в списке:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^111\.222\.333\.444 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.testsite.ru/$1  [L]
```

Оно не работает, все равно запросы c этого IP перекидывает на https.
В чем ошибка?

Comment: А зачем его переадресовывать на http? Туда он и сам как-нибудь дойдёт, а ваша проблема в том что бы **не** переадресовывать его на https.

Comment: то есть в правиле, где прописана переадресация всего дописать: RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111\.222\.333\.444 [NC] ???